# Disable some [Required] field validators in a view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations, asp.net-core-mvc

ASP.NET MVC Core if that makes any difference

Is there a simple way to disable some field validators in a model or view under certain cases?

Most information on the web looks to be from the ASP.NET Forms era.
I could not find too many things to try out but, this looks to not do the trick.

```
<label asp-for="Files.PromoImage" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <input asp-for="Files.PromoImage" class="form-control" />
    @if (Model.Content.NewArticle)
    {
        <span asp-validation-for="Files.PromoImage" class="text-danger"></span>
    }
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.All" class="text-danger"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you generate the corresponding input ? Keep in mind that using the new "asp-for" tag helper, e.g. `<input asp-for=""/>` will automatically generate validation span as well and will append data-require attributes to the input.

Comment: Added the rest of the corresponding code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input asp-for="Files.PromoImage"/>` will generate validation span and `data-required` attribute if the `PromoImage` property is marked with the `[Required]` attribute. You can check the generated html in the browser.

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to remove the `[Required]` attribute in the model and have something like this in the view:

```
@if (Model.Content.NewArticle)
{
    <input class="form-control" data-val="true" 
        data-val-required="The PromoImage field is required." name="Files.PromoImage" 
        placeholder="Promo Image" type="text" value="">        
}
else
{
    <input asp-for="Files.PromoImage" class="form-control"/>
}
```

Then again on the server, in your post action method, you have to do a manual validation for the `PromoImage` property.

Not so trivial but more elegant approach is to extend the MVC and jQuery validation with your own validation attribute and jQuery validator, e.g. `[RequiredIf]`. The API is slightly different in ASP.NET Core 1.0, but here is an example: [Custom validation](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)